# Attach to an open instance of Power Point

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am writing a simple module that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint to determine if a PowerPoint slideshow is active and if so which slide is currently being presented.  This works great when I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation to open the presentation in my code.  If possible, I want to check to see if an instance of Power Point is already open and if so attach to it instead of opening a new instance.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check by calling `Marshal.GetActiveObject ("Powerpoint.Application")`  - it gives an exception if powerpoint is not running... see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx

If it is running this gives you an object...

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i was looking for.  I check to see if the powerpnt process is running before i make the call to try to prevent the costly (time wise) exception from being thrown.

Comment: It happens sometimes that it succeeds but no actual powerpoint is on :(

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `Interop.PowerPoint.Application` and check whether your file is in the `Presentations` collection.

Unlike Word or Excel, PowerPoint is a single-instance application; your new `Application` instance will automatically connect to any open copy of PowerPoint.

Comment: I have issue with single instance. My app WPF C# uses interop when user closes the presentation should i close the app also or just presentation? within single wpf app session user may export as many times they want. So what is best recommended? to close PPT app  each time they close presentation or i should leave the ppt app open through out the wpf app life time and use the same app ?

Comment: @WPFKK: Don't close PowerPoint; the user may have other unsaved files open.